# Access variable of import class from Controller

Tags: php, laravel

how can i access the **$cleantext** variable of my import class from my controller to pass it to my view?

This is my Import Class:

```
class ExcelImport implements ToCollection
{
    /**
    * @param Collection $collection
    */


    public function collection(Collection $collection)
    {
        $array = $collection->toArray();
        $outervalues = array_values($array);
        $new_array = [];

        foreach ( $outervalues as $key => $value_inner_array  )
        {
            foreach ($value_inner_array as $key => $innervalue)
            {
               array_push($new_array, $innervalue);
            }

        }

        $text = implode(',',$new_array);
        $clean_text = str_replace(","," ", $text);
        
        $newText =  new fulltext([
            'text' => $clean_text
        ]);

        $newText->save();



    }
}
```

And this is my Controller:

```
class ExcelController extends Controller
{
     public function ExcelIndex ()
     {
         return view('CV_Test.excel');
     }

     public function ExcelToArray (Request $excelFile)

    {
         $excelFile->validate([

            'excelfile' => 'required|mimes:xlsx,xls,csv,html,ods',

             ]);

         Excel::import(new ExcelImport, $excelFile->file('excelfile'));

       return view('CV_Test.excel');


        }
}
```

I need to get the variable here to pass it via "compact" to my view.
Or is the approach totally wrong? I cant manage to do it :(

Comment: You'll need to set it to your classes `$this` scope with visibility `public`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ExcelImport implements ToCollection
{
    public $clean_text;

    /**
    * @param Collection $collection
    */


    public function collection(Collection $collection)
    {
        $array = $collection->toArray();
        $outervalues = array_values($array);
        $new_array = [];

        foreach ( $outervalues as $key => $value_inner_array  )
        {
            foreach ($value_inner_array as $key => $innervalue)
            {
               array_push($new_array, $innervalue);
            }

        }

        $text = implode(',',$new_array);
        $this->clean_text = str_replace(","," ", $text);
        
        $newText =  new fulltext([
            'text' => $clean_text
        ]);

        $newText->save();
    }
}
```

And then, after calling `collection()` method, you can do:

```
$excelImport = new ExcelImport
$clean_text = $excelImport->clean_text
```